# How to install lerna package not using NPM repository

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

I git cloned not my NodeJS package AAA. This package uses lerna. Briefly this means AAA consists of many sub modules or other many packages which will be published into NPM repository separately. For example, structure of AAA:

```
 AAA\
   packages\
     CCC\
     DDD\
```

I created my NodeJS project BBB and installed package AAA locally there:

`npm install "path/to/package/AAA"`

but this way results:

```
 BBB\
    node_modules\
        AAA\
            packages\
                     CCC\
                     DDD\
```

If I just installed the package AAA from NPM global repository

```
npm install AAA
```

it would result:

```
 BBB\
    node_modules\
        AAA\
        CCC\
        DDD\
```

Is there a way to get this structure using local installation?